# Statistics: Prediction of multiple outputs vs. one input

Tags: statistics, distribution, prediction, data-science

I have a problem and would like to hear ur expert opinion. Let's say you have a one input value (call it TotalValue) (let's say with a range of 0-10), and there are 5 output values (call it Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4, Week5).

Now, for example, if the input value is 3, they will be distributed over the output values.

So one possible data point would be: 
TotalValue: 3 --> Week1: 0, Week2: 1, Week3: 0, Week4: 1, Week5: 1

Another possible data point would be: 
TotalValue: 4 --> Week1: 2, Week2: 0, Week3: 2, Week4: 0, Week5: 0

With the condition that the sum of the output values is always equal to the Input value.

Now given that sufficient data is available, what would be the best way to go about this problem? I'm guessing multi output regression will not fair well, since we have only one input value.

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Maybe try this question on Cross Validated?  It's off-topic here.

Comment: (also there isn't a single answer to your question, you need to know something about the distribution to have any hope.   For an example of argument, the distribution could be one that specifically foils any particular predication algo you choose...)

Comment: does is matter how it is distributed ? ex if input is 4 is it okay if w1:2 w2:2 w3:0 w4:0 w5:0. also does it matter if the output is not the same on every week ex: say input is 4 output w1:1 w2:1 w3:2 w4 w5:0 ??

Comment: @George it should be probabilistic not deterministic. i.e. I have thousands of data points where there is an input value and their outputs, and I would like to predict the most probable outputs given an input. The only deterministic thing should be is that the sum of the outputs is equal to the input value.

Comment: Thx @BadZen, I can calculate the distribution, but each input value has its own distribution.